# Movie where people play games of chance in a world where luck can be captured, bought, sold, and gambled

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie many years ago on TV. Like I said above, there are people that play games of chance varying from running through a forest blindfolded to poker to Russian Roulette (which is the conclusion I think) and they wager Polaroids (and sometimes the lives) of specific people/objects because by taking a picture of something (and I think touching the thing) the luck of an object gets transferred to the picture and then to the owner.

tl;dr in this movie people literally bet the luck that is contained in pictures.

Please help me find this movie.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description! Is there any chance you could specify (even give a rough estimate of) how long ago "many years ago" is? (e.g. Is it five years ago? Ten years ago? More than that? Etc.) Do you remember what language the movie was in and/or what country it was from? Thanks!

Comment: Op already found their answer, but just incase, wiki mentions the US 2003 film The Cooler as being similar, with the same luck stealing casino motif

Answer (score 7):

I had to do some ridiculous googling and got the spanish movie "Intacto" and can confirm it is the movie I was referring to... go me!

From wiki:

> Intacto is a 2001 Spanish thriller film ... Rooted in magical realism. The film depicts an underground trade in luck, where fortune flows from those who have less to those who have more; the premise purports that luck can be amassed and transferred as any other commodity. The story follows several participants as they engage in literal games of chance, each one more risky than the last, to eliminate the unlucky.

---

> A concentration camp survivor named Samuel Berg (Max von Sydow), a preternaturally lucky fellow, runs a European casino. One of his workers is Federico (Eusebio Poncela), a man who "steals" other people's luck merely by laying a hand on them (a similar concept is used in the 2003 Las Vegas comedy-drama The Cooler).
>
> When Samuel Berg has a falling out with Federico and takes away his powers, Federico sets out to find the luckiest man alive (Leonardo Sbaraglia), the lone survivor of a plane crash, in order to use his powers to overpower Samuel Berg in the one game he has never lost: Russian roulette.
>
> Federico takes his partner through a series of tests in order to confirm his abilities. In the process, they approach the tightening circle of underground chance games that will eventually lead them both, and a female cop on their heels, to a final showdown with Samuel Berg.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intacto)</sup>

Comment: Great movie, by the way.