Looking for a movie where the plot revolves around the power of good luck
Well, I believe this movie is from the late 90s or early 2000s. I remember that in the plot, the protagonist was discovering the power of good luck and was getting involved in a series of life threatening actions in order to prove his powers.
There was some sort of handful of people who had the power to steal other's good luck. They've challenged each other through a form of a bet and the one who loses, loses his entire stack of good luck. Highlander style without loosing the head.
I also remeber that the main antagonist was a sinister old man who posseses lots of good luck stealed through the years. The protagonist was engaged in a vendetta against this old man for some reason.
It's all I've got so far. Hope it helps.

You may also want to take a look at https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49697/movie-where-people-play-games-of-chance-in-a-world-where-luck-can-be-captured-b?rq=1, as that seems a closer fit than my answer.

Definitely it is this one! Intacto (2001). The old man is played by Max Von Sydow! I knew the old man was played by some well know actor! Many thanks! Yep. We have a duplicate!

Could this be The Luck of the Irish, a Disney Channel original movie from 2001? It's about a kid who loses his lucky charm (a gold coin) and discovers he's actually part leprechaun, and has to battle against another (evil) leprechaun to win the coin (and thus his luck) back

 via a basketball match they play.

The details don't exactly seem to fit, but it's also possible you've remembered slightly incorrectly (if this is the correct answer, of course).

No. Is not it. There was no basketball involved and definitely wasn't from Disney. It was more like a drama with very adult themes. Probably european. I'm trying to remember who played the sinister old man, but no luck so far.

Max Von Sydow...check the links above.

Yep. I saw it. Thank you!
